# How to use exit code of git diff in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, shell, githooks, pre-commit-hook, husky

I have a project with a backend and a frontend, but since the git pre-commit hook gets executed for every change I need to check if the changes were made in the frontend.

I tried this pre-commit hook:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

git diff --cached --name-only --quiet frontend
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  cd frontend && npm run lint
fi
```

But for some reason it fails when running the git command -- which works fine in my terminal. The error I get is:

> husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)

That does not really help. My guess is that the git command returns an error code and the script thus ends.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `git diff` will return 1 when there are changes. `[` will also have an exit code (it needs to, otherwise `if` could not check the exit code). Do you always want to exit your script with code 0? If so, `true` as last command might help.

Comment: @knittl thanks for the answer, but could you give a hint what you mean? I have no knowledge of shell script. All I want to do is to run git diff and check if its return value is 1. If so, run the lint command. But how do I prevent git to return it to the shell and just save it for the comparison?

Comment: if you need your script to always exit with success, `true` as last command might do just that. (I already wrote this in my first comment ;)). Explanation: `true` always exits with success. A shell script exits with the same code as the command which was executed last (or with the code specified with `exit`). So actually, `exit 0` might be more explicit than `true` :)

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the syntax. I don't know _where_ to put the "true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell script always exits with the exit code of the command which was executed last or with the code specified with the `exit` builtin.

If you need your script to always exit with a specific exit code (e.g. always success, `0`), make sure you explicitly specify the exit code:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

git diff --cached --name-only --quiet frontend
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  cd frontend && npm run lint
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: But then again I'm wondering: what is the purpose of such a pre-commit hook? If linting fails, it will still exit with success, thus providing no value. Or is `npm run lint` actually formatting/changing the files?

Comment: Thank you. I was really confused because it looked like it never reaches the end.
We have a backend and frontend in the same repository, but the commit hooks belong to the repository. If a backend develop does not have the npm dependencies installed in the frontend folder their build will fail. I want to prevent that. The linter must only run if there are changes in the frontend folder.

Comment: @ctwx: then you *want* the script to exit with the exit status of `npm run lint` *if* you are running `npm run lint`. Otherwise you *want* the script to exit with status 0. An explicit, always-reached `exit 0` is therefore wrong. I'd write this as `if ! git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD -- frontend; then cd frontend && npm run lint; fi` perhaps, which should achieve that.